# JMeter execute thread groups in sequence in an infinite loop

Tags: jmeter

Cannot comeback to a previous gruop nor create a loop outside a thread group

Execute:
thread group 1
1 minute delay
thread group 2
thread group 1
1 minute delay
thread group 1
1 minute delay
thread group 2
thread group 1
1 minute delay
thread group 2
thread group 1
1 minute delay
thread group 2
thread group 1
1 minute delay
thread group 2
... (to infinity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) the scenario you've described is not supported.

It is possible to use [Include Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) or [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) to refer external [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) or [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) but you can have only Samplers or Logic Controllers there, the Thread Groups will be ignored.

With regards to your requirement you can just run your test in an endless loop using your operating system scripting mechanisms [in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) using the same [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)